# Autoclick/submit a paypal button?

Tags: forms, paypal, onload

Is it possible to automatically click the paypal "Buy now" button when the site loads?

The button is very simple but without a form I find hard to submit it:

```
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=12312313" 
data-button="buynow" 
data-name="My product" 
data-amount="1.23">
</script>
```

I should probably point out that is not for any trickery reasons. My page is simply setup in a way whereas this would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Use jQuery!

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#id_of_button_here").trigger('click');

</script>
```

For an example: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTJgt/9/)

**UPDATE**

Answer to question was eventually resolved the following way:

OP did not know that browsers can show client-side code. By using a browser to show the source code of the page she was able to retrieve the id of the server-side outputted HTML table. She could then submit the table using simple submit statements in JavaScript.

Comment: Interesting but I can't really get it to work. The example you provided is working fine, but I can not make it call the paypal script. I have tried with "buynow" and also tried to add id="text" but it won't do anything.

Comment: That's because php is loaded at server side. Try adding $(document).ready(function () { ... }); where you put the code at the dots. You can also call the php in a test page on your browser, then go into code view on your browser and search for the id of the button. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hello again. No I could not quite get it working your way but I did as you said and inspected the button element. That provided me with the actual form and enabled me to insert a form name and id. This way I can call and submit the form the old way. Thank you :)

Comment: So the actual problem was that you did not know that browsers can show you the output of server-side code? Well, then look into Firefox and Internet Explorer 9! They have amazing consoles which show you all client-side code of a website you want to see :) Good luck!